# Encoding Arabic in google charts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get data from my phpmyadmin, they are in Arabic, and they show as question marks - `???`

[image: photo of the result]

My code is:

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','kidwah');

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            Create Google Charts
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['description', 'o_owner'],
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT count(o_owner) AS count, description FROM sakk GROUP BY o_owner";

                $exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)) {

                    echo "['".$row['description']."',".$row['count']."],";
                }
                ?>
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Browser wise visits'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Pie Chart</h3>
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope someone has the solution for this kind of the problem.

Comment: Is your font supporting arabic characters?

Answer (score 0):

Certain characters (Arabic, Japanese.. etc) will appear as question marks because of the following reason, even if the charset is set to UTF-8.

You haven't set the default encoding for default characters properly.
DEFAULT CHARSET will return as UTF-8 however character_set_server will be something different.

You can change it by executing something like this in SQL

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
```

to check if this is the case.

As you most likely have

```
character_set_server latin1
```

you will need to change it to utf8.

If you want more information about this, go to the source.
[Source / more info](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/characters-appear-as-question-marks-using-mysql-204051027.html)

Comment: when I retrieve any other data from phpmyadmin, they come correctly except this one from google chart.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question then your problem is in html content code.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

change this line by

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16" />
```

Comment: I did that but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem happens when converting C# Arabic string to $Javascript string, to convert it properly use do the following:

1- Add @using $System.Web; on the top of your view page
2- Use this method to convert the string, below I'm showing conversion for items in a collection coming from a $ViewBag

```
    @{
            foreach (var item in ViewBag.Items)
            { 
   @:dataArray.push(['@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(@item.Name))', 
    @item.Price]);
            }
        }
```